# how to serve static files to a front end via rest api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm total noob when it comes to web development. I'm working on a side project. For this project I want to develop an REST API Back-end. A friend of mine will use the REST API to develop a front end with angular js.

As a technology for the development of the back-end I use Java, Spring and a MySQL database. I'm learning REST architecture and practices as I go.

So my questions is the following: What is the best way to serve static files from the back-end to the front-end? The files are supposed to be displayed via HTML image tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you put them inside your webapp, anywhere you want *except* under WEB-INF, and the web container will serve them. If they're under the directory foo/bar in the webapp, their URL will be /yourWebApp/foo/bar/some-image.jpg.

Comment: Ok, my API will just return the URL when the client performs a get?

Comment: I have no idea what your API is supposed to do. But yes, your API could (should) return a URL to images, if that's what it's for.

Comment: With the limited amount of information in regards to your requirements, I would say you have a couple options.
1. Base64 encode the file and pass the data string along with your REST service response payload and then reconstruct the image on the front end. However, I would not recommend this due to the size and performance issues it will impose.
2. Host the images on the web server or serve them from another sever and pass URLs to those resources within the REST service response which can then be used on the front end to pull and render the images. This should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, /META-INF/resources/, /resources/, static/ and public/ directories are available to serve static contents.

So you can create a static/ or public/ directory under resources/ directory and put your static contents there. And they will be accessible by: http://localhost:3000/your-file.img. (assuming the server.port is 3000)

```
<img src ="http://localhost:3000/your-file.img" />
```

You can customize these directories using spring.resources.static-locations in the application.properties.

For example:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/custom/
```

Now you can use custom/ folder under resources/ to serve static files.

ref :

https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: This answer is good, except for `http://localhost:3000/your-file.img`. You should use a templating language and a macro to get the correct URL.